# Checkbox gets unchecked even though the Code is written to only select the checkbox..can someone pls help

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, cucumber, selenium3

Scenario:
On the Screen once I navigate I have to click on the checkbox the first time only...
Next time when I run the script the checkbox should not  be unchecked.... but
Issue:
First Time if the checkbox is not selected it gets selected correctly and works as per the requirement
but the second time when I run the script the checkbox gets unselected which should not happen
Below is my Script: Can someone pls help

```
WebElement ischecked = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ui-selectbooleancheckbox')]/following::div[contains(@class,'ui-chkbox-box')][2]"));
    //String ischecked = generatestatisticscheckbox.getAttribute("checked");
    if(!ischecked.isSelected())
    {
        
        DriverUtil.waitUntilPageLoad(driver, 60);
        FormInputsUtil.clickOnCheckBox(driver, AppXPathsConstants.generatehibernatecheckbox);
         
    }
    else if(ischecked.isSelected())
    {
        System.out.println("Navigated to the bottom of the screen");
        //DriverUtil.waitUntilPageLoad(driver, 60);
        System.out.println("Checkbox: " + ischecked + "is already selected");
        
    }
```

Comment: Show html of those checkboxes

Comment: <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c"></span></div>

Answer (score 2):

The approach you are using works only with native check-boxes (i.e. `<input type="checkbox"/>`). What you have is a custom element that looks like a check-box and behaves like a check-box but which is not really a check-box from Selenium point of view.

When you have custom check-boxes you need to obtain theirs states via the CSS properties since when you check them, they change their styles to be rendered as checked.

So you need to implement custom method that would check if a checkbox has certain CSS property and if yes, return `true`, otherwise `false`.

Comment: thanks Alexey let me try and revert